# How to insert Greek pi in siunitx environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, siunitx, inline

I wrote the following equation:

```
$T = \SI{2}{\second}$
```

I need Greek Pi after the number 2. Is it possible to insert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peraphs something like this using correctly `siunitx` package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$T=\SI{2\pi}{\second}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get \frac{\pi}{\pi} upvotes for that.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hi kindest. I have not understood :-)... \frac{\pi}{\pi}=1 :-)

Comment: Yes, silly joke for saying "+1"

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh....I not have also any limit for you to "+1"..hiihihhihi

Comment: I give `1+2+3+4+...=-1/12` upvotes.

Comment: @user238301 I give you my best regards from Sicily...that is better...:-)